# Why is Set of java.util there in the API?

Tags: java, api, collections

The interface **Set** in **java.lang.util** has the exact same structure 
as **Collection** of the same package.

In the inheritance hierarchy, **AbstractSet** is 
sub- to both **Set** and **AbstractCollection**, both 
of which are sub- to **Collection**.

The other immediate descendant of Set is **SortedSet**, 
and  **SortedSet** is extending only **Set**.

What I'm wondering is, what's the gain in **Set** in **java.lang.util**-- why is it there?

If i'm not missing anything, it's not adding anything 
to the current structure or hierarchy of the API. 
All would be the same if **AbstractSet** didn't 
implement Set but just extended **AbstractCollection**, and **SortedSet** 
directly extended **Collection**.

The only thing I can think of is **Set** is there for documentation purposes.

Shouldn't be for further structuring/re-structuring the hierarchy-- that would mean 
structural modifications of the descendants and doesn't make sense.

I'm looking for verification or counter-arguments if I'm missing something here.

//===========================================

EDIT: The Q is: "Why is Set there"-- what is it adding to the structure of the APIs?"

Obvious how set is particular among collections mathematically.

Comment: Both Stephen C's answer and my answer explain why "Set is there."  I'm not sure what else you want...

Comment: Roam might be looking for something his professor's asking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's the gain in Set in java.lang.util-- why is it there?

Separating the Sets from the other Collections lets you write code so that only a Set can be passed in. Here's an example where it's useful:

```
public void sendMessageTo(Collection<String> addresses) {
    addresses.add("admin@example.com"); //The admin might now be on the list twice, and gets two emails, oops :(
    //do something
}
```

I want to change the interface to take a Set:

```
public void sendMessageTo(Set<String> addresses) {
    addresses.add("admin@example.com"); //This will add the admin if they were not already on the list, otherwise it won't because Sets don't allow duplicates
    //do something
}
```

Comment: A hook for single-handedly casting out certain collections 
as its descendants and thus as sets. saw the use of ".. instanceof Set" in an implementation in AbstractSet just now. thanks for the useful answer.

Answer (score 8):

The methods in `Set` and `Collection` have the same signatures and return types, but they have different *behavioural* contracts ... deriving from the fact that a set cannot contain "the same" element more than once.  THAT is why they are distinct interfaces.

It is not just documentation.  Since Java doesn't do "duck typing", the distinction between `Collection` and `Set` is visible in both compile time and runtime type checking.

And the distinction is a useful one.  If there was only `Collection`, then you would not be able to write methods that *require* a collection with no duplicates as an argument.

---

You write:

> Set is a copy/paste of Collection apart from the comments.

I know that.  The comments are the behavioural contract.  They are critical.  There is no other way to specify how something will *behave* in Java<sup>1, 2</sup>.

Reference:

- [Design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)

---

<sup>1 - In one or two languages, you can specify the behavioural aspect of the "contract" in the language itself.  Eiffel is the classical example ... that gave rise to the "design by contract" paradigm.</sup>

<sup>2 - In fact, the [JML](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML/index.shtml) system adds formal preconditions, postconditions and invariants to Java, and checks them using an automated theorem prover.  The problem is that it would be difficult to fully integrate this with the Java language's type system / static type checker.  (How do you statically type check something when the theorem prover says "I don't know" ... because it is not smart enough to prove/disprove the JML assertions in the code?)</sup>

Comment: Set is a copy/paste of Collection apart from the comments.

Comment: +1. Besides the duplicates, another big piece of added contract is the behavior of `equals` and `hashCode`. Two `Set`s have a well-defined definition of equality based on their elements, regardless of their implementation. Two `Collection`s don't necessarily have any equality definition other than the one in `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

A set can't contain duplicate elements. A collection can.

Comment: @Roam Not sure what you mean by funny. His answer is correct.  If you read the documentation in my answer, I think that it explains it pretty well.

Comment: @Roam What do you mean? Classes that implement the AbstractSet interface have to make sure that no duplicates exist in the collection. Classes that only implements the AbstractCollection interface don't have to implement this behavior.

Comment: What`s particular in Set among some "collection" of items is soem high school grade knowledge. the "ans being correct" doesnt mean the answer for the Q. repeat: pls see what the Q asks.

Comment: @Akinakes see the API classs hierarchies n check that w/the Q.

Comment: @Roam Try to read our answers more carefully, everything that you desire is there...

Comment: @Roam Do you mean that Set is redundant because the method names are identical with those in Collection? Even though the methods have the same names they do different things, and Set overrides the behavior of some of Collection's methods.

Answer (score 0):

A [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is a `Collection` that contains no duplicates.  For more info from the page:

> More formally, sets contain no pair of
>   elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null
>   element. As implied by its name, this interface models the
>   mathematical set abstraction.
>
> The Set interface places additional stipulations, beyond those
>   inherited from the Collection interface, on the contracts of all
>   constructors and on the contracts of the add, equals and hashCode
>   methods. Declarations for other inherited methods are also included
>   here for convenience. (The specifications accompanying these
>   declarations have been tailored to the Set interface, but they do not
>   contain any additional stipulations.)
>
> The additional stipulation on constructors is, not surprisingly, that
>   all constructors must create a set that contains no duplicate elements
>   (as defined above).

If `Set` did not exist, there would be no way to enforce uniqueness in a `Collection`.  It does not matter that the code is the same as `Collection`, `Set` exists to enforce behavioral restrictions, as in due to the defined behavior, when `Set` is `implemented`, the implementing class must adhere to its behavioral contract(s).